# Convert graph of voltage to electric field lines

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, voltage

I have a physics lab which involved connecting wires to two points on a conductive paper and supplying a voltage. We measured the voltage at every point on the paper and made a graph of the results. Is there an easy way to convert that graph to electric field lines other than just eyeballing it and drawing lines normal to the graph? The data is in Excel.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to draw the equipotential lines?

Comment: @DavidWhite No, I have the equipotential lines from the Excel graph of the voltages. I need the electric field lines which are perpendicular to the equipotential lines.

Answer (score 1):

You have equipotential lines for your graph.  This means that you have known points on those equipotential lines.  The electric field lines run perpendicular to the equipotential lines.  From algebra, given a line with a known slope, or $y=mx+b$ where $m$ is known, the line that is perpendicular to this line has a slope that is the negative reciprocal of this line, or $m_{perpendicular} = -1/m$.  Thus, given a point on your equipotential line, and a calculated perpendicular slope, you should be able to calculate points that are on the electric field lines, via the point-slope formula, such that you can produce another plot of the electric field lines in Excel.